# Corrupt page layout messing up backend - how to change layout elsewhere?

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I have a corrupt page layout and I need to know where else I can change the page layout of a page apart from editing the page itself from the frontend.

I have access to sharepoint designer 2013 but not powershell.

Anyone knows where else it can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the page layout from SharePoint designer under the Page Layouts menu on the left. You can also get to the page layouts from the browser by going to Site Settings > Master pages and page layouts.

Comment: I know where to to find and edit the page layout, what I am looking for is other places to assign a page layout to a page.
Since I have managed to corrupt it, I need to asign another layout to it as I can't access the pag via the frontend to change the layout.

Comment: Have you tried to open the "edit properties" of the page and assign a different page layout to it? You can do that from the pages library.

Comment: Well, yes. But I dont seem to have the option to change the page layout there? I can change the content type but I have nothing mentining the page layout.